# Issues with small rotation values (precision?)

Tags: three.js

Excuse me if this is an obvious question, I'm quite new to Three.js.

I'm trying to rotate some geometry along its Y axis, quite slowly and I'm using a rotation matrix for that.

In my machine, when setting a value smaller than 0.0076rad for the rotation, the geometry starts spinning, but when it reaches PI/2, it's not able to proceed, and stays flapping in values around PI/2.

Find an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/vn0m7h81/ , where the speed value can be set at...

```
// Speeds below 0.0076 cause the cube to stop spinning when reaching 
// Pi/2 rotation in the Y axis. Values > 0.0075 work fine.
var rotationSpeed = 0.0075;
```

For incr. values bigger than 0.0075 the geometry keeps spinning forever.

What's the reason for this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not modify `mesh.matrix` directly in three.js unless you are an experienced user. Instead, update `mesh.rotation` or `mesh.quaternion`, and let the renderer update the matrix for you. You can also use `mesh.rotateY( radians )`.

three.js r.73

Comment: Thanks for the advice WestLangley!